# Why the same offset of two sections in ELF?

Tags: linux, elf

Recently I noticed something in several ELF files which looks for me a bit suspicious under Linux. Taking for example "/bin/ls" file and running readelf on it I can see following:

There are 27 section headers, starting at offset 0x213b8:

```
Section Headers:
   [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk   Inf Al
[ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
[ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        0000000000000318 000318 00001c 00   A  0   0  1
[ 2] .note.gnu.property NOTE            0000000000000338 000338 000050 00   A  0   0  8
[ 3] .note.gnu.build-id NOTE            0000000000000388 000388 000024 00   A  0   0  4
[ 4] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            00000000000003ac 0003ac 000020 00   A  0   0  4
[ 5] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        00000000000003d0 0003d0 00005c 00   A  6   0  8
[ 6] .dynsym           DYNSYM          0000000000000430 000430 000bb8 18   A  7   1  8
[ 7] .dynstr           STRTAB          0000000000000fe8 000fe8 0005dd 00   A  0   0  1
[ 8] .gnu.version      VERSYM          00000000000015c6 0015c6 0000fa 02   A  6   0  2
[ 9] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED         00000000000016c0 0016c0 0000d0 00   A  7   1  8
[10] .rela.dyn         RELA            0000000000001790 001790 001ea8 18   A  6   0  8
[11] .init             PROGBITS        0000000000004000 004000 00001b 00  AX  0   0  4
[12] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000004020 004020 0133d3 00  AX  0   0 16
[13] .fini             PROGBITS        00000000000173f4 0173f4 00000d 00  AX  0   0  4
[14] .rodata           PROGBITS        0000000000018000 018000 00514f 00   A  0   0 32
[15] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS        000000000001d150 01d150 0005bc 00   A  0   0  4
[16] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        000000000001d710 01d710 0021a0 00   A  0   0  8
[17] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      0000000000020f70 01ff70 000008 08  WA  0   0  8
[18] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      0000000000020f78 01ff78 000008 08  WA  0   0  8
[19] .data.rel.ro      PROGBITS        0000000000020f80 01ff80 000af8 00  WA  0   0 32
[20] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         0000000000021a78 020a78 0001c0 10  WA  7   0  8
[21] .got              PROGBITS        0000000000021c38 020c38 0003b0 08  WA  0   0  8
[22] .data             PROGBITS        0000000000022000 021000 000278 00  WA  0   0 32
[23] .bss              NOBITS          0000000000022280 021278 001298 00  WA  0   0 32
[24] .comment          PROGBITS        0000000000000000 021278 00001b 01  MS  0   0  1
[25] .gnu_debuglink    PROGBITS        0000000000000000 021294 000010 00      0   0  4
[26] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 0212a4 00010f 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
 W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
 L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
 C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
 D (mbind), l (large), p (processor specific)
```

Taking a look at offset for section headers [23] and [24] we can see that these two sections have the same offset value of 021278. Is it possible that these 2 sections share the same offset in file? I'm not sure. Any bug here?

I noticed that also in other ELF files there are other sections that share the same offset like .bss section.

Anyone could explain why there is such conflict in offsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They share the same offset because the first of the two sections in the file is empty. BSS is used to reserve space at runtime, but that space is initialised to a known default (all zero) and isn’t stored in the binary.

Sections have offsets in the address space (the “address” column) and in the file (the “offset” column). The two don’t have to match.

In the example you show, 0x1298 bytes will be reserved in the program’s address space when it’s loaded (that’s what the “A” flag means).

Comment: So is this some kind of optimization and no bug?

Comment: Yes, it’s an optimisation, not a bug.